# Generate a unique erb template for known hosts using the same cookbook - Chef

Tags: ruby, loops, block, chef-infra, erb

I have a number of hosts that needs to use different master server hosts and unique ports in a file.  So the value of the ports and servers are known.

The end result is that my erb file should produce something of this nature for all the hosts that will run the cookbook:

```
PG_Host = -h myservername:unique_port
```

My challenge is how to get the values iterated in the recipe so depending on the short hostname when the server runs the cookbook, it picks up a specific port and a specific master server.

I am having difficulty matching the template with the erb file.  I'd like some simple solutions on making this happen.  Any pointers will be appreciated.

Here's my recipe:

```
template '/var/lib/pgsql/conf/mymonitor.sh' do
            source 'mymonitor.sh.erb'
            owner 'postgres'
            action :create
            variables(
                    master_server: 'someserver.fqn',
                    master_port: '897'
            )
end
```

Template file:

```
PG_HOST= -h <%= @master_server %>:<%= @master_port %>
```

So how do I get it to churn out the similar files for anotherserver.fqn on port 5555 etc using some kind of a loop?  I'm not sure how my variables for the other servers and their ports should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you pass to the template can be computed during chef-client runs, so in your recipe you can compute the port in the way you wish, and also the server name (`master_server`) can be calculated during chef-client run, or you can use some of the node's automatic attributes (collected by [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)) such for example `node[:hostname]` or `node[:fqdn]`. IE.:

- Passing the recipes variables dynamically

  ```
  server_port = "42#{node[:ipaddress].rpartition('.')[-1]}"

  template '/var/lib/pgsql/conf/mymonitor.sh' do
    source 'mymonitor.sh.erb'
    owner 'postgres'
    action :create
    variables(
      master_server: node[:fqdn],
      master_port: server_port
      )
  end
  ```
- Or you can use in your template node's attributes directly:

  ```
  PG_HOST= -h <%= node[:fqdn] %>:<%= node[:mycookbook][:server_port] %>
  ```

or using string interpolation

```
    PG_HOST= -h <%= "#{node[:fqdn]}:#{node[:mycookbook][:server_port]"} %>
```

EDIT:
The value of the attributes can be overridden for each node (or role), so easily you can assign different value for the attributes for each node. Check [chef attribute documentation](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) to see details about how attributes work.

Comment: Let me clarify it a little .... there's more than one master server with a different port so what goes into the file we generate is not the actual fqdn of the server running the cookbook but rather my list of master servers.  So for each host, a specific master server with a specific unique port has to be matched dynamically.

Comment: And how do you get the conditions to know which server must have each node?

Comment: That's where i'm getting confused i wanted to match the hosts with the master hosts and unique ports in an attributes list:

Comment: That's where i'm getting confused i wanted to match the hosts with the master hosts and unique ports in an attributes list:    default['mycookbook']['default']['master_server']  = 'mymaster_server:port.,myhost'  What's the best way?  The string in the template should match the host running the cookbook by selecting the correct master server based on the attributes file.

Comment: IMO the best approach would be setting (overriding) the attributes for each node (https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html). For me it's a direct solution, easy and fits very well your case; but you can also use a custom solution implementing your data in a Hash with the key the hostname of the server, and as value an array with the nodes with that server... (you can implement something like this as you wish).